# How to enable pagination on DRF GenericAPIView?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So I recently switched over from using APIView to GenericAPIView - hoping this would give me access to more DRF features - pagination being one of them.

My understanding was that I could just add this setting globally and pagination would just work on all GenericAPIViews

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 5
}
```

This does not enable pagination.

So then I also defined pagination_class as a class attribute

```
class job(GenericAPIView):

    serializer_class = JobSerializer
    pagination_class = PageNumberPaginator
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Job.objects.all()

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        if queryset.exists():
            serializer = JobSerializer(queryset, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response({"Returned empty queryset"}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Still no pagination.  This endpoint is returning over 100 records and adding string queries for ?page=1 or ?page=2 just returns the same 100+ list.

What am I doing wrong here?  I understand that I can just copy the DRF's paginator view methods inside my class - but I thought using GenericAPIView allowed me to easily leverage the built in pagination?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`ListAPIView`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview):

```
class Job(ListApiView):
    serializer_class = JobSerializer
    pagination_class = PageNumberPaginator
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Job.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of returning `Response` object your should return `self.get_paginated_response(...)`

So the end of your code would be

```
return self.get_paginated_response(self.paginate_queryset(JobSerializer(queryset, many=True).data))
```

Answer (score 0):

in your views, first import PageNumberPagination

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination
```

then write the following code

```
class LargeResultsSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 30
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 30

class PostsListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    pagination_class = LargeResultsSetPagination
```